# How to validate add row functionality in using ids in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have add row functionality. I created dynamic IDs for those input boxes. now I want to validate. When I type department name automatically highlight relationship field (this is my requirement). I tried to work this functionality but failed. Please help how to do this work.

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <label for="" class="control-label">  Dependent Name(s)</label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control name1" id="name1" onblur="getValue(this)" name="name1[]"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2">
    <label for="" class="control-label"> Relationship(s)</label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control relationship1" id="relationship1" name="relationship1[]"  />
    </div>
</diV>
<script>
    function getValue(obj){
        selectedid   = obj.id;
        selectedindexid   = $(selectedid).closest('div').next('div').next('div').find('input:text').id;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: is this a homework? ;)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've fixed outlook of your question (changed problem description and improved code formatting). Please see the editing help for more information on formatting (http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is `obj.id` is gives you only plain id you have to concate with `#` when you apply any jquery.

Just try this.

```
 selectedid = $(obj).attr('id');
 selectedindexid =  $("#"+selectedid).parent().parent().next('div').next('div').find('input:text').attr('id');
 alert(selectedindexid);
```

Comment: @rkm just click on ^ icon on answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in `$(selectedid)`
You must change to `$("#"+selectedid)`